# When doing social application development, is it ok to use my company credentials for all client work?

Tags: business, social-networks

As a web application developer, recently my work in creating Social Applications has taken a lot of momentum (specifically, Social Login buttons.)

Is it ok to use my company's social network developer credentials for this? I don't want to sign each client up for between 1 and 20 different services based on their needs. It's a lot easier to just open up my Google Console and click 'new.'

Comment: Ask your company.

Comment: You could ask the same question with https certificates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends upon what you and your company want to do as well as what the client wants.  If you are creating keys under your developer account, the client may not like that as it can interfere with going to another company.

On the otherhand, your company may like it very much as it is one more reason to stay with your company. Check with your company.